# How to reduce the distance in jquery slide?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var pokaz = 12;

var sliderValue = [4, 6, 12, 24];

$('#pokaz').slider({min:4, max:24, value: 12,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        if( sliderValue.indexOf(ui.value)===-1 ) return false;
               $( "#pokaz" ).val( ui.value)
        pokaz=ui.value; calc(pokaz)}});

function calc(pokaz){
   $('#ipokaz').html(pokaz);
}
```

```css
#pokaz {
  width: 12.5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div id="pokaz"></div><br>
<span id="ipokaz"></span>
```

So the question is:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/5xayhvb8/7/
```

The distance between values `12` and `24` is very large for winding, how can I remove intermediate "hidden" numbers, so that the distance between the winding is the same short?

Comment: Please post the code in the question itself

Comment: Ok, done, but works on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [slider()](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#steps) is just doing his job. Its step-length is relativ to the value of its steps. But of course there is a way around it. Just make the step-value of equal size and then set the real value in the [slide(event, ui)](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide) function.
Just like that.

```js
var sliderValue = [4, 6, 12, 24];

$('#ipokaz').text (sliderValue[0]);

$('#pokaz').slider ({
  min: 0, 
  max: sliderValue.length - 1, 
  slide: function (event, ui) {
    calc (sliderValue[ui.value]);
  }
});

function calc (pokaz) {
   $('#ipokaz').text (pokaz);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div id="pokaz"></div>
<br>
<span id="ipokaz"></span>
```

Comment: But the problem is, that if I wan't to use some `calc` function, to sum or smth, the values will be `0,1,2,3`, so it's not correct, they might be `4,6,12,24` `pokaz=ui.value; calc(pokaz)}}); $('#get').val(pokaz*10).toFixed() );`

Comment: @AndiCrew just pass `sliderValue[ui.value]` instead of `ui.value` to your `calc()` function.

Answer (score 1):

One solution might be just getting specific index of your values array like this:

```
$('#pokaz').slider({
  min: 0,
  max: 3,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $("#pokaz").val(sliderValue[ui.value])
    pokaz = sliderValue[ui.value];
    calc(pokaz)
  }
});
```